# IntelliJ - Diagonal scrolling (with two-finger touch)

Tags: windows, intellij-idea

On Windows you can scroll vertically with two-finger touch in IntelliJ. A horizontal two-finger swipe moves the cursor horizontally. Moving the viewport horizontally is possible by holding the SHIFT key while two-finger swiping horizontally.

Although I'd prefer the later behaviour without the need to hold SHIFT (and despite the scrolling being very slow) it works after all and helps when coding on small laptop screens.

Recently, I've used Visual Studio Code on a Mac where you can scroll in all

Is this possible in IntelliJ on Windows 10 somehow? Is there a plugin? Does it depend on my touchpad drivers or something?

Comment: Please try running IDE under this JDK: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-97#focus=Comments-27-3531302.0-0

Comment: @Andrey Thanks. Couldn't get it working on my machine, but I guess I know why it doesn't work now. I already have the JetBrains JDK installed. The problem is probably that my old touchpad's driver (last update 2015) doesn't fire the touch events mentioned in the issue tracker. Just verified that diagonal scrolling doesn't work in other applications neither.